# False Value not being propagated to classNameBindings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've set up a classNameBindings like

```
classNameBindings: ["App.controller.value:class1:class2"]
```

and it doesn't work. No class gets added. If I remove the false value (this part :class2) class1 will get added if App.controller.value is true. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: could you share a little more of the code?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently I'm using ember 0.9.8 and the double colon syntax looks like it was added in v1.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that something exists at `App.controller.value`?

What you're trying to do should work fine. At the peril of your view knowing about an application global, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad44g/) for an example.

Here is the javascript portion of the fiddle:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.someGlobal = Ember.Object.create({
    isEverythingOk: true
});

App.OkView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['App.someGlobal.isEverythingOk:class1:class2']
  , templateName: 'ok'
});​
```